# (AOSP android 9) Ninja: error: unknown target 'iso_img'

Tags: android, android-source, rom

I just wanted to mess around with Android Source code, so i Downloaded android 9 branch. I tried to compile it without any changes, and it did compiled but there were only img files. and when i try to get ISO files, it keeps giving me 
error: unknown target 'iso_img'

```
ninja: error: unknown target 'iso_img'
13:01:53 ninja failed with: exit status 1
```

Build INFO

```
============================================
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
PLATFORM_VERSION=9
TARGET_PRODUCT=aosp_x86
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=eng
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_ARCH=x86
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=x86
HOST_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_2ND_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=linux
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Linux-5.5.9-arch1-2-x86_64-Arch-Linux
HOST_CROSS_OS=windows
HOST_CROSS_ARCH=x86
HOST_CROSS_2ND_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=PI
OUT_DIR=out
============================================
```

command I am using

```
make -j4 iso_img
```

Answer (score 0):

iso files are relevant only to the x86 port of Android OS.
Regular android devices are flushed using img files,
that's why 'iso_img' is not a known target in the regular AOSP code base.

Thus you either:
- want to build AOSP for a regular Android device. In this case you need the img files generated automatically for you.
- want to build AOSP for an x86 (typically PC). In this case you should not base on AOSP, but on the x86 port : https://www.android-x86.org/